# Редирект домена на https, а все поддомены на http

Tags: .htaccess, https

Есть основной домен в кириллице xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai и множество поддоменов *.xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai
Задача стоит такая, чтобы с основного домена была переадресация на https, а все поддомены были на http.
Как такое реализовать в .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xn--80aswg\.xn--p1ai
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai/$1 [R=301,L]
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```